# Параметризованный дженерик(рефлексия в Java)

Tags: java, рефлексия

```
    public T getById(int id) {
    return entityManager.find(T.class, id);
    }
```

Ошибка: T cannot select from a type variable.
Нашел:

```
 ReflectionUtils.getGenericParameterClass(..) - не работает
```

Вопрос как передать параметризованный объект-класс?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дженерик параметры в рантайме не существуют, после компиляции они заменяются на максимально просто тип (То есть `<T>` будет заменено на `Object`,  будет заменено на Number и.т.д), для получения класса легче всего подавать его в конструктор, например

```
public class MyClass<T extends Number> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    public MyClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }
```

Тогда создать его можно предоставив компилятору самому определить Дженерик
`new MyClass<>(Integer.class);` будет эквивалентно `new MyClass<Integer>(Integer.class);`, после чего переменную `clazz` можно использовать вместо `T.class`.